# Spring-Boot MVC Template Not Loading (404 Not Found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an extremely simple Spring-Boot MVC application here that is not working. One Controller with one page not loading and receiving a 404 not found.

I put a System.out.println("Home Page") statement in the controller method and validated that it is mapped and getting fired correctly but the template isn't loading.

The error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Nov 06 23:43:51 EST 2014
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

The folder structure:

```
src/main/java
 +-Application.java
 +-WebController.java

src/main/resources
 +-templates
   +-index.html
```

Abbreviated console output:

```
Server initialized with port: 8080
Starting service Tomcat
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1947 ms
Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String app.WebController.index()
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
Started Application in 5.552 seconds (JVM running for 6.366)
Home Page
Home Page
Home Page
```

Configuration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("Home Page");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

I have an extremely simple Spring-Boot MVC application here that is not working. One Controller with one page not loading and receiving a 404 not found.

I put a System.out.println("Home Page") statement in the controller method and validated that it is mapped and getting fired correctly but the template isn't loading.

The error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Nov 06 23:43:51 EST 2014
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

The folder structure:

```
src/main/java
 +-Application.java
 +-WebController.java

src/main/resources
 +-templates
   +-index.html
```

Abbreviated console output:

```
Server initialized with port: 8080
Starting service Tomcat
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1947 ms
Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String app.WebController.index()
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
Started Application in 5.552 seconds (JVM running for 6.366)
Home Page
Home Page
Home Page
```

Configuration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("Home Page");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.App</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>App</name>
    <description>App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.181</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>App.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>   

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: show your IOC Container i mean your xml file.

Comment: show your web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: It's a Spring Boot app, so I wouldn't expect any xml (especially not web.xml).

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf? It looks like you are trying to, but it's not on the classpath.

Comment: @DaveSyer Yup I was missing Thymeleaf! Shouldn't it have thrown an error if it couldn't find "index" to give me some indication?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It looks like you don't have Thymeleaf on your class path.

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and everything should work then.

If you're still facing some issues I recommend creating new project with http://start.spring.io/

Comment: This was it! Shouldn't it have thrown an error if it couldn't find "index" to give me some indication? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem. It should have log at least

Comment: worked for me by doing that and also after doing: Maven->BuildProject

Comment: I have added it in `pom.xml` but still no luck. Don't know what I am missing.

Comment: It is still not working for me after adding this. I have started the project from beginning but still no luck, i think some master/parent configuration is missing for the project. Anyone facing this?

Comment: 9 years old and still a valid advice!

Answer (score 3):

follow this link.Nice example given
http://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }
    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

src/main/resources/templates/result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
    <a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

src/main/java/hello/Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a spring boot project from this website http://start.spring.io/, which is a spring initializer used to create a maven project with spring boot. Add web and thymeleaf dependencies and generate a project. Import the project in your IDE as maven project or use Spring tool suite.

DemoApplication.java:

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/homepage" , method = RequestMethod.GET  )
  public String sample()
  {
    return "home";
  }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MY Spring Boot Home Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a edge case and accidental. But, can be a possible reason.

Make sure you have not changed your static resource path in `application.properties` for example:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/
```

I was using this property for SwaggerUI which has other work around.
Removing this property worked.